# Redis - HMSET a json object

Tags: redis

What's the correct way to store a JSON object as the value for a pair using HMSET in red? Should I escape the JSON object like this below?

```
HMSET myhash field1 "{\"k1\":1}"
```

Comment: If you're doing it in the redis-cli, yes.

Comment: what if I want to do I using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using redis-cli, both the following commands return the same result:

```
> SET key1 '{"name":"Fred","age":25}'
> GET key1 
"{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":25}"

> SET key2 "{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":25}"
> GET key2
"{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":25}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to serialize your object to a string. Consequently, you will also need to be able to deserialize that string back to an instance of your class. One option for serializing/deserializing would be [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).